# Entities AddObject or SaveChanges

Tags: entity-framework

I would like to know a bit more about how the entity framework works. I have a collection of `MyEntity` being displayed in a combobox. The user has the option of editing the selected item or adding a new item by clicking a button. In my view model if I just hit save changes on a new object of `MyEntity` I get an error, but if I add the object first then its ok. Is there anyway for EF to detect that I have this new object and add it automatically or do I always have to add it explicitly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entity Framework is just an ORM framework, it cannot detect anything. It is up to you to add the new objects to the context using the Add() method and then call the SaveChanges() method to persist the data...

Comment: Thanks for the reply, whats the best way to check if an object is new or existing within the same function call?

Comment: Ok, so I can test the EntityState: `if (MyEntity.EntityState == EntityState.Detached)` Thanks again for the answer it prompted me to dig deeper for the solution :)